# Decoding hashed passwords for use with RODBC

Tags: r, hash, bcrypt, rodbc, password-hash

I will preface this question by saying that I am completely new to the concept of password hashing... bear with me.

I have been using the **odbcConnect** function from the **RODBC** package to establish a connection to a database.  To streamline my processes, I have been storing my password locally in a text file and then reading it in, passing it to the function to make the connection.  My custom function for establishing the connection looks something like this:

```
setconnect <- function(){
  db <-"myODBCname"
  user <- readChar("C:\\Credentials\\username.txt",file.info("C:\\Credentials\\username.txt")$size)
  pass <- readChar("C:\\Credentials\\my_password.txt", file.info("C:\\Credentials\\my_password.txt")$size)
  conn <- odbcConnect(db, uid = user, pwd = pass)
  return(conn)
}
```

I want to replace that text file with a *hashed* password to make it more secure.

I can hash a password using the **bcrypt** package's **hashpw** function like so:

```
> pass <- "myPassword"
> hash <- hashpw(pass)
> hash
[1] "$2a$12$jNtZmPwUt4pqEoTumGxK5e5MU.AgMGlygbGWyJUxMmShl7p1/VWBW"
```

Ideally, I would replace what is in the *username.txt* and *my_password.txt* file noted above with the result of this hashing, and modify my **setconnect** function to decode the hash before passing it to **odbcConnect**.

However, I have no idea how to go about decoding the hash...  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to decode a cryptographic hash, that is the point of thea hash, it is a one-way function.

One can only brute-force, that is try passwords hoping to find a matching hash, that will probably take until past the end of the Earth.

Depending on the platform there may be a secure key store to save the password.